# How does Laravel handle multiple command tasks scheduled at the same time?

Tags: laravel, cron, queue, task, scheduling

this is something that I've been thinking of for a while. How does Laravel's task scheduler handle multiple tasks scheduled at the same time?

Let's say I had 4 different commands, each set to execute at 1:15 AM:

```
$schedule->command('emails:send')->daily()->at('1:15');
$schedule->command('cache:maintenance')->daily()->at('1:15');
$schedule->command('users:remove-deleted')->daily()->at('1:15');
$schedule->command('users:notification-reminders')->daily()->at('1:15');
```

Also, for argument's sake, let's say each command took 2-5 minutes to complete. Laravel polls queue:work every minute, so what would happen at 1:16 AM if the first command hasn't completed yet? Does Laravel place the remaining commands into a queue automatically or would I have to explicitly create a queue worker for each command?

Comment: I don't know about the specifics of your question, so I'll restrict myself to a comment - but I _will_ say that if you really need them to go off at a specific time and you know there'll be variations in time, you're likely better off using regular cron jobs and keeping only less time-consuming tasks in the task scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a queue set up with multiple drivers, they can run simultaneously. Most production servers can easily handle many tasks at the same time. Otherwise, it will add them to one queue stack and be run in the order specified.